# Replacing JSP labels with JSTL keys

Tags: jstl

I am working on a web application, in which we have decided that it should support i18n.
For that we managed the resource files each for one language. And for replacing the labels on each jsp we are using fmt:message key="key_from_resource_file".
But it seems to be very time consuming process.
Is there any another way to manage the same?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not

Whatever the stack your are using you will need some files that have your localized resources and you will have to use some tag to resolve your resource, like

```
<fmt:message key="your.resource.key" />
<spring:message code="your.resource.key" />
.
.
.
etc
```